# How do I get code to exist in the scope of two or more non-nested namespaces?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, namespaces, scope

I would like an object/function to only be in the current scope when all of the necessary namespaces are being used.

For example, let's say there is an H2O(water) object.
It relies on both the hydrogen namespace and the oxygen namespace in order to be created and used.

Since water relies on both of these namespaces, here is the behaviour I would like:

```
int main(){

    using namespace oxygen;
    using namespace hydrogen;
    H2O water; //<- Works. In scope.
}


int main(){

    //using namespace oxygen;
    using namespace hydrogen;
    H2O water; //<- NOT IN SCOPE
}

int main(){

    using namespace oxygen;
    //using namespace hydrogen;
    H2O water; //<- NOT IN SCOPE
}

int main(){

    //using namespace oxygen;
    //using namespace hydrogen;
    H2O water; //<- NOT IN SCOPE
}
```

Is this possible?  If not, what alternatives are best recommended?

Comment: No, and there's no such thing as a "necessary" namespace to use a class anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No. (Fundamentally, you don't get to decide how other developers choose to reference the symbols you declare.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

I can't see where there would be much use for this. The idea that immediately comes to mind though is to have a `Molecule` that contains `Atom`s (or whatever the correct chemical terminology is -- it's been a while) and only export the `Oxygen` `Atom` in the `oxygen` namespace, and the hydrogen in its respective namespace. That would mean that a water molecule could only be constructed when both oxygen and hydrogen were visible.

---

I'm still a bit skeptical if this is the right approach though. Namespaces are used for organisation. Hiding otherwise public types doesn't particularly make sense.